# Scan for rabbit exchanges from iOS

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm trying to write something for my iOS app, using `RMQClient` that scans for existing exchanges on a rabbitmq server. I came up with this so far.

```
class AMQPExchangeScanner {
    static func scan() {
        let connection:RMQConnection = RMQConnection(uri: "amqp://user:user@abc.def.com:5672", delegate: RMQConnectionDelegateLogger())

        connection.start()

        for exchangeName in Foo.pastExchanges() {
            let channel = connection.createChannel()
            let exchange = channel.fanout(exchangeName, options: .passive)
            "scan \(exchangeName) \(exchange)".print()
            channel.close()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to determine if the exchange actually exists though. The print() statement prints exchange objects. I get a whole bunch of output in the console. I had hoped that I would get back an optional so I could do something like

```
if let exchange... {
}
```

But that doesn't appear to be the case. How do I programmatically check if the exchange is real or not? Or get at those errors? Do I need my own connection delegate and have to parse a bunch of text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to scan for existing exchanges is using [rabbitmq management HTTP API](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/rabbitmq_v3_3_4/priv/www/api/index.html) - it would be under `/api/exchanges`.

For a single exchange you could call the declare method, with passive parameter set accordingly (quoting from [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html)):

- for the declare method

  > This method creates an exchange if it does not already exist, and if
  >   the exchange exists, verifies that it is of the correct and expected
  >   class.
- for the passive bit

  > If set, the server will reply with Declare-Ok if the exchange already
  >   exists with the same name, and raise an error if not.
  >   
  > ...
  >   If not set and the exchange exists, the server MUST check that the existing exchange has the same values for type, durable, and arguments fields. The server MUST respond with Declare-Ok if the requested exchange matches these fields, and MUST raise a channel exception if not.